# why does this php contact form just download contact.php?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

i'm a total n00b when it comes to PHP (and arguably, web development in general :/), but i've taken a look at a ton of examples, comparing my code, and i just can't figure it out. basically all thats happening is the contact.php file is just getting downloaded to my computer. ugh. also, this client did not ask for any field validation, which is why theres none there. help!!

heres my html-

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                  <legend><strong>Get A Quote!</strong>
                  </legend>
                   Call me at 555-555-5555, or email me at <a href="">email@emaiul.com</a>, or use the form below.<br /><br />
                    <div class="clearfix">

                        <div class="input">
                          <input style="width:370px; height:35px; font-size:14px;" value="Name"  name="name" size="50"  type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /clearfix -->

                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="input">
                         <input style="width:370px; height:35px; font-size:14px;" value="Email"  name="email" size="50"  type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /clearfix -->

                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="input">
                          <input style="width:370px; height:35px; font-size:14px;" value="Phone"  name="phone" size="50"  type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /clearfix -->

                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="input">
                         <textarea style="width:370px; height:55px; font-size:14px;"  name="message" size="50"  type="text">Message</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /clearfix -->
                </fieldset>
                  <button type="submit" name="saveForm" style="background-image: url(static/img/btn-submit.png); width:150px; height:37px;"></button>
              </form>
```

and the php-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['saveForm'])) {
$to = "steven@urethrafranklin.org";
$subject = "Inquiry from website";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$phone_field = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
} else {
echo "Sorry, something went wrong. Please email me at user@user.com.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you 100% that php is installed on the server that this runs on? BTW: you should validate nonetheless at least on a basic level, otherwise your script is vulnerable to other people using it to send SPAM (via injection of mail headers).

Comment: Are you using [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/) or another method to execute PHP? What does your server configuration look like for executing PHP content?

Comment: Incidentally, I hope you're got [`suhosin.mail.protect`](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.mail.protect) turned on in your configuration, otherwise this would be too easy for people to abuse.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would do this other that whats mentioned about but just a note, and I could be wrong but, `$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";` should have escapes for $variables like: `$body = "From: {$name_field}\n E-Mail: {$email_field}\n Message:\n {$message}";`. I could be wrong but this was how I was taught to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, you guys are all right.

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

was helpful.
And I am now using `validate.js`. Thanks guys!